# Error on importing existing project

Tags: android

When I import a new existing project into Eclipse, I get the following error message when attempting to execute as an Android project:

1)Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

2)The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project

3)The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  Utils.java

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your default.properties problem like this:

1. Right-click your project (in the project explorer), add a new file and call it default.properties.
2. Open your project.properties file and copy paste the content to your new default.properties file

In case you don't have a project.properties file then just add your project target to your new
default.properties file. E.g for api level 17 as your target it would look like this:

target=android-17

Hope that can resolve at least your first problem - did work for me!